# How are existing VPN applications creating new profiles in Android 2.0 - 2.3?

Tags: android, vpn

After much searching on StackOverflow, it seems rooting a device in the only way to create a VPN profile pre-4.0

My question is how do the following apps do it without root?

http://www.featvpn.com/

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expressvpn.vpn&hl=en

**Update 1**

Seems private API is the way to go pre-4.0. Unfortunately, not many resources out there to get started. Does anyone know if private api still requires a rooted device?

**Update 2**

It seems you can do this using modified Android.jar or by using reflection. L2TP/IPSEC still requires rooted device. PPTP does not seem to.

[How to use internal APIs on Android](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/)

**Update 3**

Please note, this is taken from various sources. It seems root is required because VpnService starts racoon, which then runs as a system user, and retrieves the PSK from the KeyStore. So KeyStore entries created by other apps aren't visible to racoon. (In linux environment, racoon is a security process assisting in IPSEC related key negotiations - IKE).

**This makes sense, however, there are still applications which achieve L2TP/IPSEC without root.**

**Update 4**

XinkVPN, source code to get started. Still does not allow users to create L2TP profile without user having to generate a key_store and recompile. Not very market friendly but a fabulous start.

https://github.com/xinthink/xinkvpn

http://code.google.com/p/xinkvpn/

Answer (score 2):

you could just redirect the user to the VPN settings screen via an undocumented intent.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This seems to work on 1.6-4.1 phones.

Comment: The application is intended to auto-configure much of the VPN process. I have a VPNProfile being created and saved but it does not show up in the VPN settings menu.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy how did you do that? How did you make VpnProfile being created and saved?