# android , start a system activity in background and interact it with fake click events, is that possible?

Tags: android, vpn

I want to do a auto-connect VPN client on android.  Or call it VPN fastswtich. what's this soft wile do , is an android desktop widgets ,when click it , turn on/off a vpn connection.

After some google , i found it will need root the device to use android's VPNServer,

[How are existing VPN applications creating new profiles in Android 2.0 - 2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163644/how-are-existing-vpn-applications-creating-new-profiles-in-android-2-0-2-3)

Found that dev a new client to do the auto connect staff will very difficult,  I changed my
mind to using system vpn settings  "android.net.vpn.SETTINGS", 
  Now another problem come,  how can i  start  vpn setting activity("android.net.vpn.SETTINGS")  in background (or just let this activity invisible ) and send it a fake onclick event to start one vpn connection.
  so this App will look like with one desktop click then start a vpn connection.

Comment: Do it as a service.. start a service in oncreate and finish the activity there itself...

Comment: Second,For now after android-14 there are a new VPN service abstract class in the SDK, just impletment it to develop a VPN service; Three after android-14 user must be notice about the VPN started event (OS Mandatory Requirement）.Hope this u can under my Chi-english :)